# should I read from ARGV in own perl module

Tags: perl, perl-module, separation-of-concerns

My Perl extracts and processes data from (multiple) log file(s), currently processing all files in `@ARGV`.

The most important part of this script is the **log decoding** itself, it incorporates a lot of knowledge about the log file format. This transforming part from log (actually into an array of hashs) has proven to be **subject of change** (as the log format evolves), and to be the **basis for further processing** steps: there are often specific questions to answer from the decoded records which is done best right in Perl, that's why I'm thinking of making it a module.

The core function is using nested (or name it *scoped*) pattern matching sitting in a `while (<>)` loop:

```
while (<ARGV>) {
    $totalLines ++;
    if (m/^(\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d) L(\d) (.+)/) {
        my $time = $1;
        my $line = $2;
        my $event = $3;
        if ($event =~ m/^connect: (.+)$/) {
            $pendings{$line}{station} = $1;
            ...
```

...more than 200 lines follow before the closing braces.

I have the feeling that simply reading from `ARGV` would exceed the *[Do one thing and do it well](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodstyle.html#Before-you-start)* rule. When I searched the web, I found nothing that speaks explicitly *for* or *against* reading from `ARGV` in module, but maybe my search patterns were just poor. <sup>[1]</sup> <sup>[2]</sup>

**(How) should I re-frame my decoding for placing it into a module?**
<sub>...or should I change my feelings about this?</sub>

---

<sup>[1]</sup> [perltrap - perldoc.perl.org](http://perldoc.perl.org/perltrap.html) 
<sup>[2]</sup> [perlmodstyle - perldoc.perl.org](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodstyle.html)

Comment: It would be more flexible to accept a list of filenames, that way users of the module can use any data source they want.

Comment: Passing iterator sub to your module makes sense, `MyModule::method(sub{ scalar <ARGV> })`

Comment: @Сухой27 this is a thing I thought of (in C++), but I was not able to think of it in Perl. Great! Is this right: it gives one line for each call in scalar context?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen, absolutely. In my case it's also important to have this because the log contents continues over file boundaries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make your function unaware of `<ARGV>` iterator logic,

```
sub foo {
    my ($iter) = @_;

    # `defined()` should be used explicitly unlike `while (<ARGV>)`
    while (defined (my $line = $iter->())) {
        # if ..
    }
}

foo(sub{ scalar <ARGV> }); # force scalar context; one line/record per call
```

Comment: The explicit `defined` prevents from terminating on empty lines, or lines that consist entirely of `0`. Isn't having `"\n"` sufficient?

Comment: Wouldn't `my $iter = shift;` fit better here (as we see the example usage)?

Comment: If you have a properly formatted unix text file (i.e. one that has a newline at the end of every line), the `defined` is indeed unnecessary. The `defined` is there in case the last line is `0` and it doesn't include the newline.

Comment: No, `my $iter = shift;` is not better, just different. (Technically, from a self-documentation point of view, it's worse because it implies there might be more in `@_`. OTOH, `shift` is ever so slightly faster, IIRC.)

Comment: @Wolf `shift` alters `@_` array, unlike assignment. `defined` is implicit when iterating with `while` over filehandle; `perl -MO=Deparse -e 'print while <ARGV>'` => `print $_ while defined($_ = <ARGV>);`

Comment: Re "*`shift` alters `@_` array, unlike assignment.*", So what?

Comment: So it differs in that sense from assignment.

Comment: I think the term **iterator** should be stressed (in a positive way). After you brought it in your comment, I got much further with that: made my own test (after reading [Understanding and Using Iterators - Perl.com](http://www.perl.com/pub/2005/06/16/iterators.html)) right before I read your answer.

Answer (score 3):

I would write it such that it accepts any file handle. Then, you could use `\*ARGV` as the argument.

Also, don't clobber your caller's `$_`. `$_` is often aliased to other variables (which would have far-reaching consequences) and constants (which would cause your code to fail). Use your own lexically-scoped variable instead (or at least add `local *_;` first).

Comment: Would your suggestion work also with a list of file(name)s? That's what I'm actually needing.

Comment: File handles are more flexible than file names. Any reason you couldn't call the sub once for each file? In that case, you could still pass a file handle.

Comment: *`more flexible than file names`* -- well, I was not very clear about this: I currently depend on this file-list magic of Perl. But your points helped nevertheless: I removed the `$_` usages, and you made me think again about the interface (input and output). But you will certainly admit that iterators are at least as flexible as files.

Comment: For sure, though possibly overkill